# Using Apostrophes in Apex

Tags: apex, webservices, xml

I am sending an Http request who's body contains XML payload. Data sent over can have apostrophes which causes my palyload to error out. XML payload looks something like

```
<comments>testString</Ccomments>
```

where `testString` is a string variable that contains apostrophes.

I tried using

```
 string.escapeSingleQuotes(testString);
```

but this replaces `'` with `\'`

I want to replace all apostrophes with `&apos;`

Any suggestions?

Comment: How about `a = a.replace('\'', '&apos;');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [escapeHtml4 String method](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm).

```
String s1 = 
   '"<Black&White>"';
String s2 = 
   s1.escapeHtml4();
System.debug(s2);
// Output:
// &quot;&lt;Black&amp;
// White&gt;&quot;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use EncodingUtil.urlEncode(); it worked for me.
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm